# R graphics engine version 16 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed

Tags: r, rstudio

I Upgrade the latest version R (R-4.3.1-win.exe) and RStudio (RStudio-2023.06.1-524.exe) after I start R Studio It doesn't start. It Shows R Stopped working. On the other side if restored the Old version of RStudio then It shows me the above error: **R graphics engine version 16 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.** my System is a 64-bit Windows server 2012 as this is a remote desktop machine don't have an internet connection. How to fix this issue? Anyone helps? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You will need an older version of R to work with the older RStudio.  No idea why your new RStudio doesn't work.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to give information about the failure with the new RStudio, and leave out the distracting information about the old one.  Some things to add:  after installing R 4.3.1, does Rgui.exe work?  What about R.exe in a command window?  After seeing the "R Stopped working" message, can you get any more information from RStudo?

Comment: Consider installing a newer version of Rstudio. Possibly a [daily build](https://dailies.rstudio.com/).

Comment: I am having the same problem. I used the installr package and the  updateR(). I know get the same message as the top of this thread. I have tried 'check for updates' but it just says (unsurprisingly) that I have the latest version (R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default   (how do I do a carriage return without posting? ) 

TBH I'm a bit confused between R and Rstudio  - some sites seem to use the terms interchangeably but have I updated both or is there still a task outstanding? K

Comment: I should add - my R file opens and runs. It simply will not plot