# Which Rstudio, R and R Graphics Engine combinations are compatible?

Tags: r, rstudio, compatibility

## Question

An `RStudio` release supports only specific versions of `R` and `R Graphics Engine`. But **where could one find the compatibility matrix** or equivalent information?

Note: The question is analogous to [Which TensorFlow and CUDA version combinations are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525). Ideally I also expect something like the [Tensorflow tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) to be documented, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

The question ends here. Contents below are elaborated for community reference.

## Appendices

### Importance

There are many scenarios that the developer is forced to adapt the version of R to Rstudio, or vice versa. For example,

- Scenario 1: Client code with strict dependency -> You can't change R version and must use a compatible version of RStudio instead.
- Scenario 2: On a development/testing environment/team where Rstudio version is fixed -> You must use only compatible versions of R.

**Without a compatibility matrix, the environmental setup process simply goes rogue.** An installation plan won't be possible. To name a few:

- How many and which RStudio versions are required to handle all projects is unknown.
- Usable RStudio version(s) for maintaining old projects is unknown.
- Usable R version(s) on a RStudio machine is unknown.

One could end up wasting a lot of time searching but only finding limited and fragmented discussions (see References for example complaints).

### R Graphics Engine Issue

In addition, sometimes R itself could work with RStudio but not its associated graphics engine. The following message is triggered upon import of a library with visualization utilities (e.g. `library(dplyr)` or `library(ggplot2)`).

```
R graphics engine version XX is not supported by this version of RStudio.
```

This occurs with both system-installed and conda-installed combinations of (Rstudio, R). A non-working example is (`RStudio 1.1.456`, `R 4.2.0`), tested with a x86-64 laptop and Debian 12 OS.

Therefore, compatibility information of (RStudio, R) and preferably also the R Graphics Engine is strongly desired.

### References

Some complaints found by searching "RStudio R compability" on Google and SO:

- [Rstudio-2023.06.1 + R-4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935916)
- [R/Rstudio version conflict](https://github.com/Bioconductor/bioconductor_docker/issues/39)
- [R graphics engine version 15 is not supported by this version of RStudio.](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-graphics-engine-version-15-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rstudio/141359)
- [RStudio compatibility with R version 4.2.0](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-compatibility-with-r-version-4-2-0/137645)

Comment: Interesting question. Have you reached out on Posit Community and/or to Posit Support?

Comment: @r2evans No, this is the first time I've heard about it. But brief searches of "RStudio compatibility" and variants on Posit Community didn't seem to yield a comprehensive answer.

Comment: RStudio 1.1.456 is absolutely ancient. This problem probably disappears when considering versions of RStudio released within the last 2 or 3 years ...

Comment: @NirGraham Your assumption doesn't hold. A recent SO example: [Rstudio-2023.06.1 + R-4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935916). Such incompatibility is especially painful for business environments where old production projects/environments tend to stick around and hard to modify. Without a compatibility matrix, the environmental setup process simply goes rogue. Unable to plan for installation. How many RStudio versions are required to handle all projects is unknown. Usable RStudio versions for old projects and R versions for a RStudio machine, are unknown. Really unprofessional.

Comment: your counterexample, does switch one extreme for another; rather than a giant gap, between an ancient R and a modern R studio, you have linked to a hypermodern R, and fairly modern R studio; https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12751.  I'm sorry that I couldnt grace you with your desired compatibility matrix, I understand your frustrations. perhaps one day someone will be so frustrated they will set out to make such a thing